# Combine two sqlite3 queries

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Can I combine these two queries some how?

I'm getting an error of table not found in the second query, and I think its to do with some of the sqlite calls in the first query.

```
NSString *dayName = del.dayName;
int rowCount = del.tableRowNumber;

NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"banklist" ofType:@"sqlite3"];

if(sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE %@ SET recipe_name='%@' WHERE cell_id='%i'",dayName, info.name, rowCount];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [sqlStatement UTF8String] , -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [sqLiteDb UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    }
    if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE )
    {
        NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database) );
    }
    else
    {
        sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);


    NSString *sqlStatement2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE %@ SET recipe_id = (SELECT key FROM recipes WHERE name = Monday.recipe_name)",dayName];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement2;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [sqlStatement2 UTF8String] , -1, &compiledStatement2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement2, 1, [sqLiteDb UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    }
    if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement2) != SQLITE_DONE )
    {
        NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database) );
    }
    else
    {
        sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement2);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement2);
}

sqlite3_close(_database);
```

thanks

Comment: You must not call `sqlite3_step` when `sqlite3_prepare_v2` has failed. At least log the error in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. You might not want to supply the parameters to your query using `stringWithFormat`. What if the recipe was "Pat's Infamous Cookies"? That apostrophe would be interpreted as terminating your string and your prepare function will fail. You should use `?` placeholders in your SQL and bind values. See [section 3](http://sqlite.org/cintro.html) of the SQLite documentation.
2. While I'm suggesting you use the `sqlite3_bind_text` function above, you are actually are calling `sqlite3_bind_text` and passing it the path to the database file. That

   - doesn't make sense given your SQL, because you don't have any `?` placeholders to bind this value to; and
   - I'm not sure why you'd be passing it the path of the database at all.

   That call doesn't seem like it could possibly work. If you check the return code of that existing `sqlite_bind_text` call, I'd wager that it is not `SQLITE_OK`.
3. If your `sqlite3_prepare_v2` calls fail (and this is a common point of failure while you're refining your SQL), you're not logging the `sqlite3_errmsg`. The `sqlite3_errmsg` you get after a `sqlite3_prepare_v2` failure is one of the most useful error messages you will get (it will tell you precisely what is wrong with your SQL). Make sure to examine `sqlite3_errmsg` if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` does not return `SQLITE_OK`.

Thus that might yield:

```
if(sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE %@ SET recipe_name=? WHERE cell_id=?",dayName];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [sqlStatement UTF8String] , -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: prepare failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
        sqlite3_close(_database);
        return;
    }

    if (sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [info.name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: bind_text failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        sqlite3_close(_database);
        return;
    }

    if (sqlite3_bind_int( compiledStatement, 2, rowCount) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: bind_int failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        sqlite3_close(_database);
        return;
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE )
    {
        NSLog(@"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database) );
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        sqlite3_close(_database);
        return;
    }

    // you don't need this unless you're going to reuse that prepared statement, which you aren't
    //
    //else
    //{
    //    sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
    //}

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    // did you really mean to hardcode "Monday" in this SQL?

    NSString *sqlStatement2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE %@ SET recipe_id = (SELECT key FROM recipes WHERE name = Monday.recipe_name)",dayName];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement2;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [sqlStatement2 UTF8String] , -1, &compiledStatement2, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: prepare 2 failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
        sqlite3_close(_database);
        return;
    }
    if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement2) != SQLITE_DONE )
    {
        NSLog( @"Save 2 Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database) );
    }

    // again, not needed
    //
    //else
    //{
    //    sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
    //}

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement2);
}

sqlite3_close(_database);
```

I must confess that I'm not crazy about a data model where you're building SQL, dynamically supplying the table names. I'd rather see a single table with all of the days, and make `dayName` a column in that table. But what you have should work, but it's just an unusual construct.

Comment: @dev6546 No problem. By the way, you might want to consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), as that can greatly simplify your SQLite code.

Comment: @dev6546 By the way, your sub-select statement, `(SELECT key FROM recipes WHERE name = Monday.recipe_name)` looks suspect. If `Monday` is a table, you have to include that in your list of tables in the `FROM` statement.

Comment: Thanks again, I've binded all the values now. How do I have to change my subselect statement?

Comment: @dev6546 Let's move this to chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36822/combine-two-sqlite3-queries

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an error in this part of the statement:

```
SELECT key
FROM recipes
WHERE name = Monday.recipe_name
```

Comment: Agreed. That looks highly suspect. I would have thought that he needs the `Monday` table (assuming that is indeed a table) in the `FROM` clause.